# Java Chart Library for Display Parts Within a Container

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, charts, jfreechart

In a my Java project I want to create a chart like this
[image]

The Java charting library should allow to define filled parts as for example like

```
 new Range("Class A", 0, 40); //blue color part - from 0 to 40
 new Range("CLass B", 40, 100); //purple color part - from 40 to 100
 new Range("Class C", 120, 135); //Yellow color part - from 120 to 135
```

Also that class should allow to update the chart at run-time. What are the good Java charting libraries to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) you can also use orsonchart beans which can be used in Netbeans.

Also try one of these:-

- [charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)
- [GRAL Java Graphing](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/wiki/Gallery)
- [JChart2D](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/screenshots.shtml)

Comment: Note that answers can be edited to add more links.  I edited your answer, and also put the descriptive name of the link (in a list). +1

Answer (score 1):

As far as good charts go, I would recommend highcharts. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ I'm not sure if it can do exactly what you want, but it probably can. It is pretty customisable. Also it is free for non-commercial use and can be used with java http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/42-highcharts-on-the-server

Comment: Is this available for java? I need a Java library.

Comment: It says here http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/42-highcharts-on-the-server[link] that you can use it with java.

Comment: Since I am working on a java swing based application if the library is supporting swing that is good.

Comment: @Sachindra: or just roll your own solution. It shouldn't be that difficult to do if this is an academic project. If this is professional, that may be a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FusionCharts XT](http://fusioncharts.com/).

Comment: Yeah.. It works very well - http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?Code/J2EE/JSP_GettingStarted.html..

Comment: Also try out their sample dashboards (select Java from the drop-down menu) - http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/sample-applications/